# Angular - How can I toggle the visibility of an element in a component from another component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I have the following scenario in my Angular app:

A component `MainDashboardComponent` that is visible when I have the route `/`. Obviously I have the `<router-outlet>` tag in my `app.component.html` file, which looks like this:

```
<app-side-menu></app-side-menu>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a `SideMenuComponent` I use to have a side menu on all my routes. In `MainDashboardComponent` I have a method that for some reason needs to toggle a chat element that is situated on the side menu.
Inside the `SideMenuComponent` I have a method that handles the visibility toggle for the chat element and it works as expected. How can I call this method from my `MainDashboardComponent` and toggle the chat element from there?

**What I tried with no success**

I tried to inject the `SideMenuComponent` inside my `MainDashboardComponent` but, though the method `toggleChat()` is called, the element doesn't change it's visibility. Looks like I have a kind of multiple instance of the same component I guess...

Can you please help me with this? Thank you!

**MainDashboardComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './main-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class MainDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  setFocus(id) {
    // here I'd like to call SideMenuComponent togglechat() ... 
  }
}
```

**SideMenuComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-menu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.scss']
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  showChat: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.showChat = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleChat() {
    this.showChat = !this.showChat;
  }

}
```

Comment: can you add full code for that

Comment: which is your MainDashboardComponent ? Is MainDashboardComponent one of the route?

Comment: I've update my question :)

Comment: you can make `toggleChat()` method to static and in `setFocus(id) { SideMenuComponent.toggleChat()`

Comment: @Suryan doing this I have to set the `showChat` property to `static` too. How can I access it from the template?

Comment: You can also take the leverage of rxjs BehaviorSubject

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To communicate between different components, there are different ways.

- If you want to communicate between parent and child component, you can use **EventEmitter** to emit event from child component and handle the event in your parent component
- If you want to communicate between any components, you can use **Service** and implement communication with the help of **EventEmitter** or **Subject/BehaviorSubject**

In your case, we can create a service, myService.ts and declare and eventEmitter

**.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppCommonService {

 toggle : EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>()

}
```

**mainDashboard.component.ts**

```
constructor(private myService : myService){}

chatStatus : boolean = false;
ngOnInit(){
 this.myService.toggle.subscribe(status=>this.chatStatus = status);
}

toggleChat(){
 this.myService.toggle.emit(!this.chatStatus);
}
```

**sideMenu.component.ts**

```
constructor(private myService : myService){}

chatStatus : boolean = false;

ngOnInit(){
  this.myService.toggle.subscribe(status=>this.chatStatus = status);
}
```

Comment: Great and simple solution! Exactly what I was looking for! I never had a case like this and never thought how to do this kind of things, will keep it in mind from now on :) Thank you Sarthak!

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is the domain of a service!

- Just create a service and add the "showCat" property.
- Inject the service into both components
- Alter SideMenuComponent to:

  ```
  toggleChat() {
      this.myService.showChat = !this.myService.showChat;
  }
  ```
- Alter MainDashboardComponent, also use *this.myService.showChat* to show / hide your chat window

**Service TS**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{
  showCat:boolean = true
}
```

**MainDashboardComponent**

```
toggleChat() {
   this.myService.showChat = !this.myService.showChat;
}
```

**SideMenuComponent**

```
chatVisiblity = this.myService.showCat //<-- bind this to the element attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

You could efficiently use child to parent communication in this scenario. You'll need to create a custom event using angular's **EventEmitter** in your *SideMenuComponent* and use it in your *MainDashboardComponent*.

So, here is some code that may help you -

```
// SideMenuComponent
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-side-menu',
    templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.scss']
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();
    showChat: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.showChat = false;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    toggleChat() {
        this.showChat = !this.showChat;
        this.valueChange.emit(this.showChat);
    }

}

// MainDashboardComponent
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-main-dashboard',
    template: `<app-side-menu (valueChange)='setFocus($event)'></app-side-menu>`
    styleUrls: ['./main-dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class MainDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    setFocus(event) {
        // check for required input value 
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

> Refer these tutorials if required - 
>   https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular,
>   https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/responding_to_component_events.html